# Continuous numbers of 3 or less - RegEx

Tags: regex, passwords

I am developing a password complexity requirements. One requirement is not have the user input 3 consecutive numbers in the password. What is the regular expression?

For example

```
Allowed: Stack254!
Allowed: Stack254!36@
Disallowed: Stack8763^
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
^(?!.*?\d{4}).+$
```

This won't allow the string which has atleast 4 consecutive numbers.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yG6wZ5/1)

Comment: Thank You @AvinashRaj. I have this RegEx. How can I add the rule in this expression?       /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,),+,?])([a-zA-Z0-9-!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,),+,?]{7,})$/

Comment: here `/^(?=.*[0-9])(?!.*?\d{4})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,,?,_,~,-,(,),+,?])([a-zA‌​-Z0-9-!,@,#,$,%,^,&,,?,_,~,-,(,),+,?]{7,})$/`

Comment: oh, you don't need to sepearte the special chars with comma.. `(?=.*[!@#$%^&` would do the job..

Comment: Thank you Avinash. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Avinash, I have a password meter and would like the meter look for any 3+ continuous numbers? My code here.  if(val.length > 7 && val.match(/[a-z]/) && val.match(/[A-Z]/) && val.match(/?!\d{4}/) && val.match(/.[!@#$%^&*?_~-()]/)) level = 4;